# Add scrollbar without breaking responsiveness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I failed to add a scrollbar while keeping a responsive page. To add a scrollbar to my datatables I can use the code

`"scrollY": "200px"`

but that sets the table size to 200 px and not 100 %. Is it possible to use a variable somehow so that the table both fills out the area and gets a scrollbar for the items that are beyond the page size?

Comment: did you try setting "true" instead of 200px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
height: 100vh;
```

else

```
height: calc(100vh - your other element's height);
```

after that use

```
overflow-y: auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `"overflow-y" : "scroll"`. Like this, a grayed out scrollbar is present when it's not needed, and a normal one when it's needed. Therefore, it will no longer disturb your layout if it appears/disappears.

Comment: What could the reasons be if it didn't work? I added the `overflow-y` to my datatables configurations but a scrollbar didn't appear and the data is overflowing the page without a scrollbar. Could there be something in my config that overrides my setting? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: @DjDac Right click > inspect element is overflow-y: scroll overrided or not? You should find your answer there